# On change radio button to no the span should hide in angular

Tags: angularjs

In angular if i change my radio button from no to yes the span content should Hide.
I don't know how to take the event.

Here the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgqnkx9/

```
      <div class="onoffswitch-green1">
          <input type="radio" id="radios3" name="radiosgg" class="SwitchOn" value="true"  checked 
           ng-click="radioChecked()">
          <label for="radios3">Yes</label>
          <input type="radio" id="radios4" name="radiosgg" class="SwitchOff" value="false" ng-
           click="radiounChecked()">
          <label for="radios4">No</label>
        </div>
              <span class="temsize">
        <label>Team Size</label>
        <input type="text" class="s-txtboxes">
        </span>
```

your ans  will be very helpfull .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<kbd>[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmtrLzbf/)</kbd>**

Angular has an already defined behavior for handling radio inputs. You don't have to use any `radioChecked` function, just use combination of `ng-model` and `value` on your `input`s :

```
<input type="radio"
       ng-model="hasTeam"
       value="true"/> - Yes

<input type="radio"
       ng-model="hasTeam"
       value="false"/> - No

<span ng-if="hasTeam">
  I'm showing only if yes is selected.
</span>
```

Maybe you should [read the docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).

Comment: meriadec its working but onload no radio button is selected, only when we select its working, u can check the same link, what is the reason?

Comment: its because `hasTeam` is not defined at start, so evaluated to `false`. you can initialize it in your controller (and use `ng-value` instead of `value` for use boolean type instead of string). example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wd0rcaj/

Answer (score 0):

you must use ng-hide or ng-show directive

for example

HTML

```
 <input type="radio" id="radios3" name="radiosgg" class="SwitchOn" value="true"  checked 
           ng-click="radioChecked()" ng-model="myvar" ng-hide="hideVar">
```

JavaScript

```
$Scope.hideVar = false;
$Scope.myvar = false;

$Scope.radioChecked= function () {
   $Scope.hideVar = true;  // Hide your checkbox
   ... dosomething... 
}
```